# Run a script on pipenv venv on ssh with nohup

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, virtualenv, nohup

I want the remote script to run even if I lost ssh connection. I found that where to put `nohup` command is confusing.

For example, I want to run the follwing line via `ssh`.

```
cd path/to/venv && pipenv run python3 main.py
```

What I tried:

1. `nohup` at the beginning of the command.

```
ssh 'user'@'host' 'nohup cd path/to/venv && pipenv run python3 main.py'

# Won't work.
```

2. `nohup` on `pipenv`

```
ssh 'user'@'host' 'cd path/to/venv && nohup pipenv run python3 main.py'

# Seems working.
```

3. `nohup` on `python3`

```
ssh 'user'@'host' 'cd path/to/venv && pipenv run nohup python3 main.py'

# Seems working.
```

While 2. or 3. seems working, I think inappropriate application of `nohup` would mess up the process in the end. What would be the most appropriate application of `nohup`?

Comment: Try Linux Screen or tmux, you can see the result of script

Comment: 2. or 3. both seems running without interruption. The result would be 0. Should I conclude both are appropriate?

Comment: If you want run script on a server try [GNU Screen](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/) you can detach or attach session. When lost connection just reattch it and you can see the result or do smt :)))

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but how to watch the results is not a solution I'm looking for here. The candidates I posted seem to work in some circumstances, while they might fail in other time. I cannot conduct all the possible circumstances. That is why I want to find out "the most appropriate" approach, i.e. conceptually, structurally correct application of the `nohup` command.